# My Rasberry Pi do not let me install software because I don't have permission to write

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie, readwrite

When I want to install a package or do an apt-get update, the system returns an error like (read-only file system) can you help me please.
I have Raspbian Stretch Lite.

I did not download other packages because I can not install anything on the system.

Command: `sudo apt-get update`

Error messages are like: `Err 3: mirrordirector.rasbian.org/debian streatch Release open (30: Read-only file system) Could not create temporary file to work with`

Comment: You should also [edit] to clarify whether this is this a new installation; have you been able to install packages previously? Might the SD card be write-locked?

Comment: command: sudo apt-get update
error messages are like: Err 3: http://mirrordirector.rasbian.org/debian streatch Release
open (30: Read-only file system)
Could not create temporary file to work with ...

Comment: It sounds like you have a corrupted file system.  Flash the SD card again.  If it still fails get another SD card.